# Count records in a related table

Tags: mysql, count

I have three tables: items, members, subscriptions.
One item can be get by 1 or more members (one member can get more items), so subscriptions represents the many-to-many relationship between items and members.
So we have:

- items(*id*, name)
- members(*id*, name, email)
- subscriptions(*id_item*, *id_member*)

And now my problem: I have a quite comlicated query which manage items and outputs items data, I want to add to this output a column that contains the number of members who subscribed that item.
I wrote this query but I don't want to use sub select statement

```
SELECT
(SELECT count(*) AS current_sub from subscriptions AS s where s.id_item = i.id) AS current_members,
  -- ..... other code....
FROM items AS i
WHERE
// ....other code...
```

I use MySQL 5.5. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one might work better:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
items AS i
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_item, COUNT(*) AS count_subs FROM subscriptions GROUP BY id_item) counts
      ON i.id = counts.id_item
WHERE
....
```

Post the result of the query with `EXPLAIN` keyword in front of `SELECT`. Then we can see, if and how indexes are used.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Regarding EXPLAIN, here there's the row of subscriptions table (table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra): subscriptions|index|NULL|id_item|6|NULL|5|Using index.